# Virtual box error "failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i just came across this error in virtual box and i cannot fix it. hyper-v is disabled and just 12 hours ago i was using the VM normally. I have checked all over the internet but found no solution. please Help. I also came across the same question on this site but all the solutions there did not solve the issue for me.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYND6.png)

[windows features screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2cOA.png)

Comment: What are the details of the first screenshot?

Comment: it is what the error is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the trouble I went through, I just could not wait any longer and had no option other than to perform a fresh install which ironically fixed the issue. 
thanks to @harrymc for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes that may help with this problem:

- Open VirtualBox as administrator
- Install [platform package](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Right-click on the VM and click on "Discard Saved State"
- Ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows optional components
- Uninstall and reinstall the latest version of VirtualBox.

Comment: I have tried all of the above sir but i still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Try this trick : disable the VM Network adapter and boot.

Comment: i have sir, same error. I actually tried that before posting here, i even tried it on another machine and it works fine. What bugs me is it was working just the day before. why now!

Comment: Try to uninstall, then scrub from the disk all data mentioning oracle or virtualbox, searching for all variants possible, then reinstall.

Comment: I actually used "revo uninstaller" to remove it and perform a fresh install first. I really don't want to reinstall windows all over again! I can't figure it out.

Comment: Revo may not find everything. You may also try `chksk` and `sfc /scannow` and upgrade Windows to itself.